# PutHive3Streaming processor missing in nifi 1.14.0

Tags: hive, apache-nifi

I'm seeing examples of using `PutHive3Streaming` processor on the internet, but can't find it in my installation of `nifi 1.14.0`. Was this functionality merged with `PutHive3Streaming` processor maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: `PutHiveStreaming` is this available?

Comment: Yes, `PutHiveStreaming` is available

Comment: Did you try using it?

Answer (score 0):

puthive3streaming nars are left out of the nifi binaries intentionally to reduce the size of the resulting nifi binary see here https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.14.0/nifi-assembly/pom.xml#L923.
To include it, clone the nifi project and activate the profile (include-hive3) to include nifi-hive3 nar.